# Entity Framework code first; Can't add a connection for my DbContext (SQL Server LocalDB)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ef-code-first, localdb

I've created a DbContext. The guide I'm following says that my DbContext should show up under "Select or enter a database name" in the "Add Connection" window. It doesn't for some reason. Can anyone help me figure out why?

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB and Visual Studio 2010.

[Here's a picture of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TbDl.png)

Comment: The image you have provided is a dialog used to establish a connection to a SQL Server database.  This dialog is not aware of DbContext or EF.  It could be used to define the connection that will be ultimately used by the DbContext class though.

Comment: All the guides I've looked at say that you should be able to select the DBContext to create a DB using it. [For example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj193542.aspx). Am I missing something?